How to file tax return for tax refund without German bank account
I came to Berlin to work in April 2024. But due to personal reasons I am going back to London. In this time I have collected 3 salaries and my total salary after tax is approx 5500 Euros which is like 53 days of work. I  decided to leave job early and was not able to arrange a German bank account in that time. Since my salary is under allowance limit I guess I am eligible for tax refund? But because I was paid salary in my UK bank account will I still be able to apply for tax return?


Since my salary is under allowance limit I guess I am eligible for tax refund?

Maybe or maybe not.
I'm no tax specialist, but when I had part of my income in Italy and part in Germany a while ago (and tax residency still in Germany), the German tax office asked me to list also the Italian income since that factors into the total annual income which Germany uses to determine the rate at which your German income is taxed. This is laid down in double taxation agreements (more precisely: agreement to avoid double taxation).

But because I was paid salary in my UK bank account will I still be able to apply for tax return?

I would not expect your bank account country to matter except that the UK bank may charge you fees on receiving or sending EUR.
